# How to pass data from Struts2 Interceptor class to an ActionSupport class

Tags: struts2

What is the appropriate way to pass a String variable from an Struts2 Interceptor class to an invoked `ActionSupport` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical technique is the one used by all the action-modifying interceptors.

The action implements an interface with a setter. In the interceptor, check to see if the action is an instance of that interface. If it is, call the interface's setter with the string in question.

You don't *need* to do that, you could, for example, use reflection to see if a specific method exists, and call it if it does, or annotate the method, etc. IMO the interface is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I ended up using the reflection method.

Comment: @john No problem. It's probably not an issue, but reflection will end up being slower. It's also a little bit of spooky-action-at-a-distance, but that can be mitigated with documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not getting value when goto action after interceptor.

Add one default stack give below within your action tag in struts.xml for forwarding your value from interceptor to action.rest of the thing will be same.

```
     <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
```